# Ordering Set by Instant

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, java.time.instant

I have a Java `Set` that I give information to:

```
Set<myData> dataLocations = getData(location);
```

I would like to sort this Set I have tried a sortedSet and couldn't get it to work, so I tried this

```
dataLocations = dataLocations.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(myData -> myData.expDtTm)).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The only problem is that in the Java documentation it doesn't guarantee retaining any orders. So I tried this:

```
TreeSet<myData> sortedDataLocations = dataLocations.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(myData -> myData.expDtTm)).collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet<myData>));
```

needless to say it didn't work so anyone that has any other ideas they would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please use an ordered data structure, such as a `List`. So use `Collectors.toList()` after sorting.

Comment: Basic definition of `myData`, I guess an instance of a custom class? Define *couldn't get it to work* any exceptions, error messages or a specific order of elements?

Comment: `TreeSet` has [a constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)) that takes a `Comparator`.

Comment: @Slaw But `Collectors.toSet()` doesn't take a set factory. So you won't know which exact `Set` implementation you get

Comment: A `TreeSet` with a `Comparator` as shown in the answer below is a good way to handle this. Something else to add to your toolbox: `LinkedHashSet` is a `Set` implementation whose iteration order is the same as the element insertion order.

Comment: @ernest_k Correct. But you can use `Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(comparator))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) and provide a comparator

```
TreeSet<myData> sorted = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(MyData::expDtTm));
sorted.addAll(dataLocations);
```

Or as described in [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) class Javadocs create your own collector for `TreeSet`:

```
Collector<Widget, ?, TreeSet<Widget>> intoSet =
     Collector.of(
         TreeSet::new, 
         TreeSet::add,
         (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; }
     );
```

Comment: Instead of creating a custom `Collector` directly, you can simply use `Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(yourComparator));`. It takes care of the accumulating and combining for you.

Answer (score 3):

Your third attempt was close though as written doesn't compile. The method [`Collectors.toCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toCollection(java.util.function.Supplier)) takes a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) that returns the desired [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), not the `Collection` itself.

If `MyData` was defined as:

```
public class MyData {
  private Instant instant;
  public Instant getInstant() { return instant; }
  public void setInstant(Instant instant) { this.instant = instant; }
}
```

Then in order to collect them into a [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) via [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)s you could do:

```
Comparator<MyData> comparator = Comparator.comparing(MyData::getInstant);
TreeSet<MyData> set = getMyData().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(comparator));
```

Note that I don't use [`Stream.sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted(java.util.Comparator)) here. It is actually detrimental if you *were* to use `Stream.sorted` because it adds work that doesn't help the end result. The `Stream` would sort its elements and then later start adding them to the [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) which *will also sort the elements*.

That said, there are cases where using `Stream.sorted` would be beneficial: when [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.stream.Collector)) returns a `Collection` that guarantees insertion order. A [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), as well as any implementation of [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html), guarantee insertion order. So you could do:

```
LinkedHashSet<MyData> set = getMyData().stream()
            .sorted(comparator)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
// Or use a List
List<MyData> list = getMyData().stream()
            .distinct() // If you want only unique elements in the end List
            .sorted(comparator)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*Note: It is not enough that the end `Collection` guarantees insertion order. The [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) being used must not have [unordered](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html#UNORDERED) as a [characteristic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#characteristics()). This is the case with the `Collector`s returned by `Collectors.toCollection` and [`Collectors.toList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()). It is **not** the case when using [`Collectors.toSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet())*.

Answer (score 1):

You try this:

```
public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comparator<String> stringComparator =
      Comparator.comparing((String x) -> x);

    Supplier<TreeSet<String>> supplier =
      () -> new TreeSet<>(stringComparator);

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("1", "3", "7", "2", "9", "4"));
    TreeSet<String> treeSet = set.stream()
      .collect(Collectors.toCollection(supplier));
    System.out.println(treeSet);
  }
}
```

Replace String class to yours.

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was:

```
TreeSet<myData> sorted = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(myData -> myData.ExpDtTm);
```

Now this is not the best answer and I'm still looking for another on because if you have 2 ExpDtTm that are the same the comparator will delete the second Instant meaning:

```
| Lot Number | ExpDtTm             |
| LOT-4      | 2018-07-16 12:41:56 |
| LOT-7      | 2018-07-16 12:41:56 |
```

This will cause ***LOT-7*** to be deleted and not returned to user.

```
NOTE: This is also the time that happens when formatting an Instant to just have a date which I did 
for testing purposes
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Comparator<MyData> instantComparator = Comparator
            .comparing(MyData::getExpDtTm)
            .thenComparing(MyData::getLotNo);
    SortedSet<MyData> sorted = new TreeSet<>(instantComparator);
    sorted.addAll(dataLocations);
```

I tried this with the following set:

```
LOT-9 2018-07-15T10:39:53Z
LOT-1 2018-07-17T14:46:57Z
LOT-4 2018-07-16T12:41:56Z
LOT-7 2018-07-16T12:41:56Z
```

After sorting it became:

```
LOT-9 2018-07-15T10:39:53Z
LOT-4 2018-07-16T12:41:56Z
LOT-7 2018-07-16T12:41:56Z
LOT-1 2018-07-17T14:46:57Z
```

A set is a mathematical set, it may contain each element only once. A `SortedSet` like a `TreeSet` uses its comparator (or the natural ordering of elements if no comparator is supplied) to decide whether two elements are equal and hence cannot both be in the set. So in order to sort the elements by the `Instant` and still keep elements with the same `Instant` we need to distinguish them some other way. So in my comparator I have added sorting by lot no. after `Instant`. If lot no. isn’t unique either, you will want to add a further list of attributes on which to sort.